# Managing cryptographic random number generators in a Haskell web application

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm writing an application which I want to be able to supply RSA encrypted tokens to clients via a web API.

I'm using the [`crypto-pubkey` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/crypto-pubkey/0.1.3/doc/html/Crypto-PubKey-RSA.html) for RSA, for example:

```
encrypt :: CPRG g
    => g          -- ^ random number generator.
    -> OAEPParams -- ^ OAEP params to use for encryption.
    -> PublicKey  -- ^ Public key.
    -> ByteString -- ^ Message to encrypt
    -> (Either Error ByteString, g)
```

In my case, the message is the AES content key used to encrypt the token. I can create a [`CPRG`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/crypto-random-api/0.2.0/doc/html/Crypto-Random-API.html) instance using the `cprng-aes` library which provides an AES counter mode implementation:

```
makeSystem :: IO AESRNG
```

which is the same implementation that Yesod uses in its `ClientSession` module. I've taken a look at that and it stores a global instance behind an `IORef` and uses it to implement a function for generating initialization vectors inside an `atomicModifyIORef` call.

This is OK since the function just pulls some bytes out of the generator and returns them, writing the new CPRG instance back to the IORef. However the RSA API needs to be passed a  `CPRG` instance directly, and even if I could carry out my token generation within a call to `atomicModifyIORef`, it's likely to be a much more costly operation and lead to contention issues.

One idea I had was to pull out adequate data from a global instance in advance before calling the encryption API, and wrap it up in a `CPRG` instance backed by a `ByteString`, but that's a bit of a fragile hack, as it requires prior knowledge of the internals of the token generation process -- the content key size, RSA padding and so on, which may vary depending on the parameters chosen.

What are the best options for managing the random number generators required by pure functions like the above RSA API when they are used in multi-threaded client-server applications?

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the actual problem code?  Such as, you have a generator in an IORef, an entity using the generation, and this RSA encryption routine.  I am unclear how these entities contend for the (just one?) RNG.  FYI, generally in a multi-threaded environment you will have one RNG per thread.

Comment: I was just referring to the IORef example in client session since that's the only place I can find the AES CPRG used in anger. The exact code I'm calling probably doesn't really matter (and I'm still working out the best way to write it). Let's just say I want to call `Crypto.PubKey.RSA.OAEP.encrypt` in a Yesod Handler function, for example (or equivalent HTTP request handling code). How to manage an instance per thread sounds like what I'm looking for, but I haven't found any code that does that, so if you can point me to some that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a pool of CPRG instances, *if the numbers say you need this*. It's probably worth doing some basic profiling first to see if the simple atomicModifyIORef approach would be a bottleneck.

For pools, you can use http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool, or http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pool-conduit (which is based on resource-pool).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There aren't any numbers yet, because it's not a real-world application :-), but I can see that it might be an issue when building a more complex API on top of functions which require a CPRG. Another thing that I couldn't reconcile with using this approach is that in theory I don't know how much data an encrypt call is using, so managing reseeding of the generator by keeping a count of the bytes as `ClientSession` does wouldn't be possible. On closer inspection though, the CPRG instance makes its internal state available through `cprgNeedReseed`, so I can use that.